# Auto-close xml-tags

Tags: xml, eclipse, aptana, aptana3

When editing xml-files in my Eclipse 3.7.2 with the Aptana-plugin 3.1.1, it will not autoclose xml-tags. 
It used to automatically insert a closing xml-tag, when I finished typing the opening tag.

I think I already have the relevant options ticked of: XML -> XML Files -> Editor -> Typing: Insert a matching end tag.

I really liked this feature of the XML-editor, but it stopped working some months ago.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it my install of Eclipse 3.7.0 and it is working for me.  Make sure that you're opening the file with the XML editor by right-clicking on the XML file in the Package Explorer and choose Open With-->XML Editor.

Comment: This worked for me, you can set the XML editor as the default via Window > Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations. Do you know offhand if there's any major behavioral differences between the HTML/XML editors?